# How do I create, write to and deploy a text file containing build and release information in TFS Release Management?

Tags: tfs

During a deployment in Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2015 i'd like to

1. Create a new text file called release.txt
2. Write to the file the Release Id, Release name, TFS Build number and Date
3. Deploy this file along with a website

So that I can go to that file at the root of the website and see what version of the codebase is live.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Write a PowerShell script that takes the parameters you want to capture.

Turn it into a custom Tool that takes those parameters (Arguments would be, for example: `-BuildNumber '__Build Number__'`).

Make a new Component that uses that tool.

Pass in the parameters (e.g. `$(BuildNumber)`)

The system variables you can pass in are:

> - **ApplicationPath** Destination path, including the component name, where the component is copied.
> - **ApplicationPathRoot** Destination path where the component is copied. The default is C:\Windows\dtlDownloads. You can over-ride this
>     value to specify an alternative destination path.
> - **BuildDefinition** Build definition for the component.
> - **BuildNumber** Build number for the component.
> - **Environment** The environment for the release.
> - **PackageLocation** The source path from which the component is copied. For builds dropped to a Standard server, the path points to
>     the container-id. For builds dropped to Azure, the path points to the
>     storage blob GUID.
> - **ReleaseId** The ID of the release; this is assigned by Release Management.
> - **ReleaseNumber** The number of the release.
> - **Stage** The stage of the release.
> - **Tag** Tag used to group the server which is running the action.
> - **TeamProject** Team project for the component.
> - **TFSUrl** TFS URL for the component.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn834972(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your using WebDeploy you could add the release info file to your web application with blank/default values and use [Parameterization](http://dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/) to transform it during your deployment using the [SetParam](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) flag on your MSDeploy or deploy.cmd call.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=D:\package.zip -dest:auto,computername=mycompuetrname -setParam:name="ReleaseId",value="$(ReleaseId)" -setParam:name="BuildNumber",value="$(BuildNumber)"
```